# Odd ProtonMail text modification in drafts

Tags: protonmail

I have a text stored in ProtonMail's draft message.

Once, I logon and I see odd modifications to my message:

- seems like `<` has been changed to `&lt;`.
- seems like `>` has been changed to `&gt;`
- occurrences of `&nbsp;`
- occurrences of `<osv>`
- some other odd occurrences and modifications

What's the cause of this? How can I stop text in drafts from being modified?

Answer (score 1):

- login to your ProtonMail
- open a Compose window and switch to **Plain Text** mode:

  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Characters like < (less than) and > (greater thn) are called HTML entities. I managed to duplicate the problem and the answer of user0 should work. However, since this is unexpected behavior, you should report it.